# How to use Android kotlin internal constants for formatting GPS location data

Tags: android, kotlin, gps, constants, location

I am learning how to use Location Manager in Android kotlin to access GPS data.  I currently have a simple working android app to display the current GPS position and time but the format of the data is not ideal.  eg. the GPS time is displayed in milliseconds from 1st January 1970 !  I wanted to display the time of the GPS position reading in a more user friendly format along the lines of "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS".  I could obviously write my own conversion routine, but I see that there are a number of android internal constants available for formatting output from the GPS sensor.

eg for GPS positions:-
FORMAT_SECONDS gives "DDD:MM:SS.SSSSS" where D indicates degrees, M indicates minutes of arc, and S indicates seconds of arc.

How can these internal constants be used to format the GPS time / GPS position?

Here is a fragment of my MainActivity.kt :-

```
val gps0: Long = location.time
val gps1: Double = location.latitude
val gps2: Double = location.longitude
val gps3: Float = location.accuracy

val textView0 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timePosn)
textView0.text = "$gps0 ms."

val textView1 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.latitudePosn)
textView1.text = "$gps1 deg."

val textView2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.longitudePosn)
textView2.text = "$gps2 deg."

val textView3 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.accuracyPosn)
textView3.text = "${gps3.toInt()} m."
```

I would welcome any helpful suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [SimpleDateFormatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) to format the date in the way you want

For example, you can do the following:

```
val formattedDate = formatDate(location.time);

private fun formatDate(timestampInMillis: Long): String? {
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
    return sdf.format(Date(timestampInMillis))
}
```

If you want to format the GPS data, you can use [Location.convert()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#convert(double,%20int))

Comment: Many thanks - very helpful, I will look into that.  Any ideas on how to use FORMAT_SECONDS gives "DDD:MM:SS.SSSSS" for positions?  Thanks.

Comment: Use `Location.convert()`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#convert(double,%20int)